# How to add a number to a certain index in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
list = [4, 7, 5, 3]
```

In this list i understand that the number 4 has an index of 0, 7 has 1, 5 has 2 and 3 has 3, but how would i add a value to an individual index?

```
(list[1] + 1)
```

I thought that the above would would make it so that when i print the list it would give:

```
print(list)

[4, 8, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Don't call your variable `list`, it overrides the builtin.

Comment: list is a reserved keyword! we are never allow to use that to assign a value to.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do (you weren't actually giving a value with `=`, so once you did the addition the result was just thrown away):

```
list[1] += 1  # Short for list[1] = list[1] + 1
```

Integers are **immutable**, so you can't modify them in place. *You need to re-assign to the name to change its value*- so here we assign a new number which is 1 greater than the last.

Now it works with a demo:

```
>>> list1 = [4, 7, 5, 3]
>>> list1[1] += 1
>>> print(list1)
[4, 8, 5, 3]
```

---

Only don't name a variable `list`, it masks the built-in.

Comment: @user3382238 If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it? You can do it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so it turns green and stays green. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = [4, 7, 5, 3]
>>> lst[1]
7
```

To modify value of an item in a list, you assign new value to it by `lst[i] = new_value`

To increment existing value, you may calculate new value to assign:

```
>>> lst[1] = lst[1] + 1
>>> lst[1]
8
```

There is also short notation for adding value to an existing value using `+=`:

```
>>> lst[1] += 1
>>> lst[1]
9
```